# How to prepend a string that starts with a number with string from same row in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (`df`):

```
col_1      col_2 col_3 col_4
sample_001 fjsah AB    11-110
sample_002 dfshb CD    20-210
sample_003 fsvhb EF    N3-303
sample_004 dfbkk GH    Q4-444
sample_005 gnddl IJ    55-005
```

I want to prepend the string in `col_3` to the respective string in `col_4` only if the string in `col_4` starts with a number, such that the `df` is as follows:

```
col_1      col_2 col_3 col_4
sample_001 fjsah AB    AB11-110
sample_002 dfshb CD    CD20-210
sample_003 fsvhb EF    N3-303
sample_004 dfbkk GH    Q4-444
sample_005 gnddl IJ    IJ55-005
```

I am able to identify which `col_4` strings start with a number with:

```
for n in df['col_4']:
    if n[0].isdigit():
        print(n)
```

but I can't figure out how to make the "selective merge" happen in the for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Series.str[0].str.isdigit()` to create a series of boolean indicating if the first character in each row is a digit or not, and you can use this masking along with `.loc` to modify the values:

```py
df.loc[df['col_4'].str[0].str.isdigit(), 'col_4'] = df['col_3']+df['col_4']

# df
        col_1  col_2 col_3     col_4
0  sample_001  fjsah    AB  AB11-110
1  sample_002  dfshb    CD  CD20-210
2  sample_003  fsvhb    EF    N3-303
3  sample_004  dfbkk    GH    Q4-444
4  sample_005  gnddl    IJ  IJ55-005
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way - with `apply` and `lambda` -

```py
df.loc[:, 'col_4'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col_3'] + row['col_4'] if row['col_4'][0].isdigit() else row['col_4'], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
        col_1  col_2 col_3     col_4
0  sample_001  fjsah    AB  AB11-110
1  sample_002  dfshb    CD  CD20-210
2  sample_003  fsvhb    EF    N3-303
3  sample_004  dfbkk    GH    Q4-444
4  sample_005  gnddl    IJ  IJ55-005
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function encapsulating that logic and apply it by row.

```
def f(row):
    try:
        number = int(row.col_4[0])
        return f'{row.col_3}{row.col_4}'
    except ValueError:
        return row.col_4

df['new_col'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

        col_1  col_2 col_3   col_4   new_col
0  sample_001  fjsah    AB  11-110  AB11-110
1  sample_002  dfshb    CD  20-210  CD20-210
2  sample_003  fsvhb    EF  N3-303    N3-303
3  sample_004  dfbkk    GH  Q4-444    Q4-444
4  sample_005  gnddl    IJ  55-005  IJ55-005
```